# texttospeak.QUEUE_ADD constant is not working

Tags: android

I am working on Texttospeech interface. in which I am adding some text after some processing. according to google android developer you have to write a constant in speak method as TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD but it is not working for me can nay one help me on this .

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_bus);
        textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipEditText);
        welcomeNote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeTextView);
        text = welcomeNote.getText().toString();
       speakText=   text.concat(" , Please wait we are retriving information");
        System.out.println("1 "+ speakText);
        IP = getIntent().getExtras().getString("IP");

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {


             @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    //tts.setSpeechRate(1.1f);
                    speakOut( speakText);
                    //tts.speak(IP, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                }
            }
        });

           //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://"+IP+"/checkingbusno.php");
            List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BusStopName", "thakur_complex"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
            textView.setText(result);
            //initialising  once again tts value 
            tts.speak(result, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }   





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    private void speakOut(String text) {

        //String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you add some code on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `tts.speak(result, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);` is being done BEFORE the tts has been initialized.

The `QUEUE_ADD` flag is there to handle simultaneous requests to speak AFTER it has been initialized. Suppose your tts is already speaking and you want it to speak something else. In that case, you add it to the queue to be spoken next. Either way, using flush or adding to queue, you need to call `tts.speak()` after `onInit()` has returned with `status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS`.

EDIT:

Where you have:

```
tts.speak(result, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);
```

Replace it with:

```
speakText = result;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but i am calling after initalising oninit method

Comment: No, you are not. When you call `new TextToSpeech()` you have no guarantees that the `onInit()` will be called immediately next. Your `onCreate()` method will very likely continue with the rest of its code all the way down to the `tts.speak()` call before the call back to the `onInit()`.

Comment: One simple solution: On your `onCreate()`, add your text to speak to a global variable. When your `onInit()` is called, refer to this global variable to get the text to speak back.

Comment: I have declared it as global varibale only.

Comment: it will change the op only

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41698/discussion-between-ashishsingh-and-ricardo)